# What's wrong with my Calculated Column Formula Syntax?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint list with 2 columns: Age and Age Group. The age groupings I want to display in the second columns are:

- Under 16
- 16-20
- 21-30
- 31+

This is the formula I've tried:

```
=IF([Age]<16;"Under 16";IF([Age]<21;"16-20";IF([Age]<31;"21-30";"31+")))
```

But this returns a Syntax Error. Can anyone spot whats wrong with the formula?

Comment: Try using comma ( `,`) instead of semicolon (`;`). let me know if it works. Also, make sure you are using correct display name of your column.

Comment: What is data/column type of [Age] column, Number or single line of text?

Comment: [Age] is a calculated column that returns an Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula syntax looks good to me. Try using comma ( `,` ) instead of semicolon ( `;` ) everywhere in formula like:

```
=IF([Age]<16,"Under 16",IF([Age]<21,"16-20",IF([Age]<31,"21-30","31+")))
```

Assuming `[Age]` column is of type **Number**.

**Calculated column settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes semicolon(`;`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use comma(`,`) instead of semicolon(`;`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

---

If `[Age]` column is of type **Single line of text**, use this formula:

```
=IF(VALUE([Age])<16,"Under 16",IF(VALUE([Age])<21,"16-20",IF(VALUE([Age])<31,"21-30","31+")))
```